# Загрузка проекта в Github | Git

Tags: git, github

Не могу понять как загрузить через консоль git папку с проектом.

```
git config --local --list ---------------------- $ git config --local --list core.repositoryformatversion=0 core.filemode=false core.bare=false core.logallrefupdates=true core.symlinks=false core.ignorecase=true lfs.repositoryformatversion=0 remote.origin.url=https://.git remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* branch.main.remote=origin branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main branch.second_branch.vscode-merge-base=origin/main branch.second_branch.remote=origin branch.second_branch.merge=refs/heads/second_branch
```

```
git status ----- On branch main Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 3 commits. (use "git push" to publish your local commits) Untracked files: (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) ../lab1/ nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Куда загрузить? На гитхаб? В существующий проект? Папку изначально создали на компьютере или через команду git clone создали?

Comment: Да, я хочу загрузить весь свой проект на гитхаб в существующий репозиторий. Папку изначально создавал на компьютере

Comment: На всякий случай приложите к вопросу результат команд из корня проекта: 
`git config --local --list` и `git status`

Comment: Не понял вас, можете объяснить подробнее? Я написал эти команды в терминал и получил такое: для git status ----- On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../lab1/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: для git config --local --list ---------------------- $ git config --local --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
lfs.repositoryformatversion=0
remote.origin.url=https://.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
branch.second_branch.vscode-merge-base=origin/main
branch.second_branch.remote=origin
branch.second_branch.merge=refs/heads/second_branch

Comment: Можно отредактировать вопрос, приложив туда эти данные в нормальном виде.

Comment: @Alexsandr отслеживание нет, используйте git add.